# "Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting.." how to prevent this? I've checked other problems

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've checked other answers since I saw similar ones here, none seemed to work, but I'm not to good with htaccess

Here's my htacess 
 "

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm getting a lot of these

"Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable confguration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

I saw this answer somewhere on this site,

"use RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
To make sure the RewriteRule doesn't apply to internal subrequests"

I was wondering if that would work? and if so, where can I place inside my htaccess for it to work?

If that's not the solution, what can I do?

Comment: Turn on logging as [described here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) and edit your question to include the log it generates. That will help us track down what exactly is causing it. This seems a very generic wordpress .htaccess file. The two conditions do a subrequest, but should not generate exceed the limit.

Comment: Would I have to wait for the problem to occur again for the logs to generate if I turn it on ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to turn on logging, restart Apache, then recreate the problem.

Comment: The problem will only occur on a boost of traffic though that would be something random this week, it's not something I can recreate easily, are we speaking of the error logs here?

Comment: I mean if the problem is "Exceeding the number of subrequests",
would  -> RewriteRule . /index.php [L] changed to   RewriteRule . /index.php [NS,L] work?

Comment: Possibly. Possibly not. I don't see a reason why the rule would be used in subrequests in the first place. `!-f` and `!-d` do subrequests to check if the requested file or directory exists, which might also cause this problem. Only logs can tell us what is really happening.